# how to monitor adf pipeline from CI/CD pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I have a CD Pipeline which triggers an azure data factory(adf) pipeline but it(CD pipeline) doesn't wait to proceed with next tasks until the(adf) pipeline completes. I wanna know that is there any inbuilt capabilities in CD pipeline through which i can trigger as well as monitor adf pipeline.

So, my desired outcome is that CD pipeline should wait for adf pipeline to complete before proceeding with next tasks in CD pipeline.

Comment: Do you use PowerShell to start the ADF run? There is no native activity to trigger-and-wait task for Azure DevOps, but it should not be too difficult to achieve this with a powershell script.

Comment: I am using native activity to trigger ADF, trying to use native activity as much as possible :) . but seems like this requires  powershell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following Powershell script from Azure DevOps.

```
$resourceGroupName  = "yourresourcegroup"
$DataFactoryName    = "yourdatafactory"
$pipelineName       = "yourpipeline"
$pollFrequency      = 1

$executionId = Invoke-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -PipelineName $pipelineName

$runStatus = (Get-AzDataFactoryV2PipelineRun -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -PipelineRunId $executionId).Status
While ($runStatus -eq 'InProgress') {

    Write-Host ("Pipeline {0} in progress" -f $pipelineName)
    Start-Sleep $pollFrequency

    $runStatus = (Get-AzDataFactoryV2PipelineRun -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -PipelineRunId $executionId).Status
}

Write-Host ("Pipeline {0} finished with status {1}" -f $pipelineName, $runStatus)
```